# Logstash/Grok Add field from Grok Filter

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

Here is my logstash pipeline. I have tested the grok pattern and it works. But the field `dagid` is just printing **%{dag_id}** instead of replacing it with the real value.

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => { "path" => "%{WORD:opt}/%{WORD:fps2}/%{WORD:airflow}/%{WORD:logs}/%{WORD:dag_id}/%{WORD:task_id}/%{GREEDYDATA:execution_date}/%{WORD:try_number}" }   
    } 
    
    mutate {
        add_field => { "dagid" => "%{dag_id}" } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you paste an example logs to check more ??

Comment: You can use [replace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace) which is a mutate filter options

Comment: is dag_id an actual field of the document?